# ./a.out on visual studio code on windows wont work - gives a 'look for an app in the Microsoft Store' prompt

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I am trying to run a simple hello world code of CPP. Nothing fancy. Just a couple of header files with a basic hello world class.

I have the following sequence of commands.

```
g++ -c HelloWorld.cpp -o HelloWorld.o
g++ -c main.cpp -o main.o
g++  HelloWorld.o main.o -o a.out
```

All goes well. Then, I do the next logical step to run the program.

```
./a.out
```

Instead of giving me the output in the terminal, I get the following prompt. I apologize for uploading a mobile phone taken photo. I try to screen grab, the prompt goes away.

[image]

So, how do I get the output in the terminal as expected?

Note 1 : I am already able to get this working on Mac OS. So, I know the code works fine, so does visual studio code. This must be some windows issue.

Comment: Name it `a.exe`

Comment: @MarkTolonen you mean, something like g++ -c HelloWorld.cpp -o HelloWorld.exe

Comment: Okay, that worked. I will update an answer below if it helps others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[with help from comments from @MarkTolonen above]

```
g++ -c HelloWorld.cpp -o HelloWorld.exe
g++ -c main.cpp -o main.exe
g++  HelloWorld.exe main.exe -o a.exe
./a.exe
```

The above worked for me.